# How does SymmetricDS convert Oracle RAW to Postgres BYTEA?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, postgresql, symmetricds

I'm using SymmetricDS to replicate data from an Oracle DB to a Postgres DB, and let it create the schema in the Postgres slave. A column with type RAW in Oracle was converted to BYTEA in Postgres. Values are converted as such

```
RAW:     24E1EB73A5CA0D17E05400144FF9F89C
BYTEA: \x24E1EB73A5CA0D17E05400144FF9F89C
```

I.e., somewhere in the process, the value gets prepended with `\x`. Querying using the prepended string in `psql` works fine. However, when I try to query it from my Rails application, I only get empty results, both with the RAW string and the prepended BYTEA string. If I try to use the suggested Rails util methods like `escape_bytea()`, I get a string that looks like this

```
\\x3234453145423733413543413044313745303534303031343446463946383943
```

Is this the format SymmetricDS should have used to input the data in the Postgres DB? Or is there a way to tweak the query string so I can get the results on the current format?

Comment: I think SymmetricDS replicates appropriately to bytea columns.  I am wondering if your bytea_output setting is set to hex or escape?

Comment: Your're thinking about the Postgres setting? On the connection used from Rails I've tried both `variables: { bytea_output: 'escape' }` and `variables: { bytea_output: 'hex' }`, with the following error result on the Rails server `Encoding::UndefinedConversionError ("\xAF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8)`.

Comment: If I print the field in the Rails model, it looks like this: `"\x1E\xAF7\xBE\x92\xA6;\xE9\xE0T\x00\x14O\xF9\xF8\x9C"`, regardless of the `bytea_output` setting (not the same value as in the original post)